# Wget fails with 500, Server Error - But the browser shows the page fine

Tags: browser, wget

I can open up http://delta.com fine. 
However when I do a wget on the same url, it returns HTTP 500, Server Error. 
Can somebody explain the reason for that discrepency

Thanks, 
John

Comment: have you tried setting the agent-string?

Comment: I just did, still doesn't work. I could be doing something wrong though

Answer (score 3):

The website seems to be trying to do some work based on the language, it works fine with an `Accept-Language` header.

```
wget --header='Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5' http://delta.com
```

Comment: Hi Olafur,  Thanks for pointing that out. It works. My next question is how did you figure that out. I tried to do `wget http://delta.com --debug` but I could not figure out if it is something to do with the language

Comment: I just tried with a few default headers that might be missing, that one was the one that did the trick.

Comment: You can just use your browser's developer tools to interpret the Request. Goto the Network or Net section based on your browser. for each request you will see Request Headers and Response Headers, check the Request Headers, try and add all possible headers from this list to your request in wget.

Answer (score 2):

If the site works in the browser, it is possibly rejecting wget's user agent or trying to do some work based on the language.

To fix it, you can include `--header` and `--user-agent`.

In your browser, let's say that you are using Chrome, go to Network and then go to the location of that URL. Then, check the Request Headers and use in the command what you have in `Accept-Language` and `User-Agent`. For instance:

```
wget --header='Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-PT;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.3,gl;q=0.2,hu;q=0.1' --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" -c "http://..." -w 1
```